# Regular Expression to match sentence with one variable word

Tags: java, regex

How do I match a list of words using regular expression.

Like I want to match

```
This is a apple
This is a orange
This is a peach
```

I tried `This is a [apple|range|peach]`.

Does not work.

Any ideas? I've sent 5 hours on this, there are "rules" published, but without exhaustive examples, these rules are too mystic.

Comment: Basically it would work if you used () rather than [].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "This is a (apple|orange|peach)" );

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( "This is a orange" );
    if( matcher.find() ) {
        System.out.println( matcher.group( 1 ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This is a ((?:(?:apple|orange|peach)/?)+)
```

will match

```
This is a apple/orange/peach.
```

whatever the order is .

You will get only one capturing group representing the all list.
(here "apple/orange/peach").

- '`(?:apple|orange|peach)`' means: match one of those three terms, do not capture it
- '`(?:.../?)+`': match a string finished by '/' or not, multiple times
- '`(...)`': capture the all list.

---

> This is an apple <-match This is an orange <-match This is a peach <-match This is a banana <-no match.

```
This is a (apple|orange|peach)
```

is enough: `[apple|orange|peach]` that you tried is actually a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and would match any 'a', 'p', '|', 'o', ... etc.

Comment: No no no no no .

This is an apple <-match
This is an orange <-match
This is a peach <-match
This is a banana <-no match.

That's what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Java regexes, but it will be something like

/(apple|orange|peach)/

ie, group them, and use | to say 'or'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = "This is a peach";
boolean matches = str.matches("(apple|orange|peach)");
```

If you use a pattern, then you can use

```
String str = "This is a peach";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(apple|orange|peach)");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(str);
boolean matches = matcher.find();
```

Comment: I'm using pattern in Java. How can i fit this in?